# Passing large data set from Flask to Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there any memory efficient way to pass large data set from flask into Jinja2 template, and iteratively display the data?

Flask Route:

```
@application.route("/get_report", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_report():
    huge_list_of_data = retrieve_report_from_db()
    return render_template('display_report.html',
                       **{'report_data': huge_list_of_data})
```

Jinja2 Template (display_report.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>My Report</title></head>
<body>
...
{% for item in data_report %}
    {% if item.get('determinant_param') %}
       <tr><td>item['param1']</td>....<td>item['paramN']</td></tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to load and display the data passed from `/get_report` as fast as possible.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific...

Comment: See the now edited version, hope it helps?

Comment: How large data are we talking here?

Comment: Say a list containing about 20,000 dicts, to be displayed as a paginated table

Comment: Then your endpoint should receive an argument to paginate and send to the template only the necessary data. Then the template should contain the buttons to handle the endpoint. I'd try to move the if statement out of the template and into the endpoint or even your retrieve function.

Comment: Indeed, you might even consider exposing the data as an API endpoint and using JavaScript to load it into the page as needed.  But you could also render an initial batch directly into the template if you want it to appear immediately upon page load.

Comment: Great suggestions! I was initially trying to load entire data set, as I was using a jquery plugin to render the data, which doesn't give the flexibility to load the data in batches. But I'm now going to write a custom paginator to provide the flexibility I need. But just out of curiosity, is there any pythonic technique that would allow loading such large data set at once and efficiently?